# Introduction to threading - Process xml file

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading, locking, threadpool

I have never written multi-threaded code before (barring a few basic backgroundworker tricks) and am hoping for some guidance about how I would approach my problem.

I have an XML file which is a serialized `List<Stock>`. For each one of these stock items I need to perform a webservice call called `UpdatePrice()`.

What I want to do is take each one of these items, create a threadpool (who's size depends on the amount of rows I will need to process) and begin making webservice calls.

I am not asking for a complete solution (obviously) but would really appreciate some guidance about how one would typically solve this problem.

The biggest issue that I see arising is how I would designate which threads would work on which objects. Do I simply take the list divide it by the number of threads I make and split the work? Or am I better off allowing each thread to arbitrarily pick an item from the list to process? (Then I have locking issues but as a plus can ensure no thread is idle)

As I said before I am not looking for a complete solution but just some basic guidance on where to start because honestly I am lost on this one and haven't written a single line of code.

PS: Also are autogenerated webservice proxies in .NET threadsafe?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and PLINQ for a solution. A simple example solution using `Parallel.ForEach()` could look like this (parallel calls limited to 5 in the example).

```
List<Stock> stocks;
Parallel.ForEach(stocks, 
                 new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, 
                 (stock) =>
{
    float newPrice = UpdatePrice(stock.TickerSymbol); //web service call
    stock.Price = newPrice;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. It seems trivially simple! Could you please advise what the name of the => operator is (or whatever is the correct terminology)? It looks like some kind of delegate assignment and I have seen it before but would like to learn more.

Comment: => is a lambda expression by which you can create anonymous function calls. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

i would:

- First read the whole XML data synchronously.
- Then, i would put each element to be processed in a single queue.
- Then, you can spawn N processing threads, in which at the beginning of each one, it would "pop" an element of your queue, wrapping this specific piece of code in a mutex / semaphore (Google C# mutex, or concurrent access, or anything related). This is easily done in C# with the "lock" keyword on an arbitrary object.

Hope this helps.
Pierre.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in using threads here.  A thread can only give you one resource: more cpu cycles, provided that you have a CPU with multiple cores.  That is not the resource that you need to speed up your program.  You need a faster Internet connection.

If you have an UI you don't want frozen then the BackgroundWorker tricks will work just fine.

Comment: Don't know that I would agree with you there. Provided you have the bandwidth threaded calls to an individual webservice will work faster then a single threaded process. This is the principle behind applications like Free Download Manager, no?

Comment: A web service doesn't behave like a http or ftp server.  But ask the site owner if they throttle connections to be sure.  And if they do, whether you are allowed to bypass it.  Surely you are not.  They'll boot you if you try anyway.

Comment: Yes a webservice doesn't work like an ftp server (although a webservice IS a http server - but this is semantics). The key point is that whether you have a webservice, ftp or http service you have a specific amount of work to perform. Usually the limitation specifically in a http request is not the bandwidth but rather the ping times. So if you are able to break this work up into multiple concurrent calls the results would be positive. Having said that, it's a valid point that they may throttle ip's or calls by specific users. I'll have to find out.